# How to disable automatic adding "www." and ".com" between host name when entering in address bar

Tags: google-chrome, url

When I search on Google Chrome's address bar, automatically added "www." and ".com" between the search word. I do not know the reproducibility conditions, but in many cases, the problem occurs by below process:

1. Focus on address bar, and select any of part in the string of address bar.

   - domain
   - colon
   - all of the search string
2. In the state of condition 1 completed, enter return when the string of address bar is not split by space.

Example (string of address bar → string of address bar after entering return code):

- localhost→www.localhost.com
  127.0.0.1→www.127.0.0.1.com
- chrome://about→chrome://www.about.com
- foo:8080→www.foo.com:8080
- foo.com→foo.com
- foo.jp→foo.jp
- foo bar→foo bar

In Firefox, I searched a solution that switches "browser.fixup.alternate.enabled" variable to false, but I don't know how to solve in Google Chrome.

I already tried below:
- Disable "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar" variable.
- Clear cache by accessing "chrome://net-internals/#dns".
- I confirmed to reproduce even in secret window.

How do I do to solve this state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved.
This is caused by Chrome keyboard shortcut.
When you type a site name + Ctrl + Enter in the address bar, **www. and .com are added to a site name**, and this concatenated url is opened in the current tab.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en